# Criação de um Chat em PHP e MySQL e Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

Estou criando um chat dentro de um painel administrativo, como tem varios na web.

Estou tendo problemas para "bolar" como iria controlar o chat de forma que, por exemplo, somente os usuarios daquele determinado nivel, exemplo `FREE USER` possam conversar entre si.

O usuário loga como `FREE USER` e vê quem esta logado no painel administrativo como `FREE USER`, ai clica no usuário e automaticamente acrescenta ele no chat.

Mas como esse controle pode ser feito? Quero utilizar `MySQL`.

Comment: acho que ainda compensa uma visita no [tour] e [ask] e [O que devo perguntar?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: Roger, criar a mesma pergunta várias vezes não é algo útil. Minha sugestão é que você edite a questão e adicione as informações úteis.

Comment: Eu se fosse você daria uma olhada no https://mibew.org/ e me basearia nele